# subtract two rows values using t-sql

Tags: t-sql, sybase

i want to subtract values from of month 7 salary from month 8 salary
using t-sql can anyone help me i m new in tsql

```
ID      Year    Month       Salary
1088    2017    8       -29766.250  0.000
1088    2015    7       -58.500 0.000
```

Comment: Don't you have any idea how to approach the problem? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Why the `sybase` tag? ARe you really targeting `Sybase`?

Comment: How do you select the rows? Just *any* `month 8`, no matter the year? Or do you want the sums of each month? Why is `ID` repeated? DO you want to compare monthly salaries per *employee*? It's impossible to give *any* answer unless you explain what you actually want to do. Each requirement needs a *different* query

Comment: i just want to select month with year. don't need any some. want to subtract previous month salary with current salary to show the difference

Comment: And in your example 07/2015 is previous to 08/2017, because there are no records stored in between these months? And 08/2017 is the current month, because there is no later month stored in the table? (And the duplicate IDs are just a typo, I guess? Because a table's ID should be unique of course in order to identify a record.)

Comment: @Ussama you have to explain what you want, in the question itself. `I just want to select month with year` doesn't explain anything, when the dates are 2 years apart. Maybe you do have only 2 rows in your table, so you only need to add the `LAG()` function to your `SELECT` statement. Maybe you do have only two rows for that specific ID. Maybe not.

Comment: By the way: With your comment you are altering your request completely. You wanted to know how to subtract the salaries of the two records shown and I've answered this. Now you want to know how to take the current salary and subtract the previous from it. I suggest you make this a new request, explaing *exactly* what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach: use a subquery for each value (i.e. replace `a` and `b` in `select a - b` with subqueries):

```
select 
  (select salary from mytable where year = 2017 and month = 8) -
  (select salary from mytable where year = 2015 and month = 7) as diff;
```